# Unable to Select List Element looking for solution when element has no usable ID

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

The html page contains two containers. Each container has two columns, the left for selectable list items and the right for selected list items. So once you click on the list item it moves from the left column to the right column.

The first container is for associated clients.

The second container is for countries.

They both use similar code without a unique id or name.
HTML code for first container:

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="tab-section">
<h3 class="section-header"> Associated Client(s) </h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="ClientControlDiv">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 450px;">
<select id="AssociatedClientList" class="multi-select" name="AssociatedClientList" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
<div id="ms-AssociatedClientList" class="ms-container">
<div class="ms-selectable">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1" style="height: 250px; width: 200px;">
<li id="3ce0a0cc_378d_4477_8787_84033319940f-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable ms-hover">
<span>(Test) 3M</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="ms-selection">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<div class="panel-title">Selected Client(s)</div>
</div>
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1" style="height: 250px; width: 200px;">
<li id="3ce0a0cc_378d_4477_8787_84033319940f-selection" class="ms-elem-selection" style="display: none;">
<span>(Test) 3M</span>
</li>
```

HTML code for second container for countries:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="DesignationControlDiv">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 450px;">
<select id="AssociatedDesignationsList" class="multi-select" name="AssociatedDesignationsList" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
<div id="ms-AssociatedDesignationsList" class="ms-container">
<div class="ms-selectable">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1" style="height: 250px; width: 200px;">
<li id="d86b9350_aa83_43c7_bc2b_5fc7f5c6ccae-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable ms-hover">
<span>Afghanistan</span>
</li>
</div>
<div class="ms-selection">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1" style="height: 250px; width: 200px;">
<li id="d86b9350_aa83_43c7_bc2b_5fc7f5c6ccae-selection" class="ms-elem-selection" style="display: none;">
<span>Afghanistan</span>
</li>
```

Once selected the html code is:

```
<div class="ms-selection">
<div class="panel-heading ">
<div class="panel-title">Selected Client(s)</div>
</div>
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1" style="height: 250px; width: 200px;">
<li id="3ce0a0cc_378d_4477_8787_84033319940f-selection" class="ms-elem-selection ms-selected ms-hover" style="">
<span>(Test) 3M</span>
</li>
```

Ruby code I tried both:

```
@b.select_list(:class => "ms-list").li(:text => "(Test) 3M").when_present.select
@b.select_list(:class => "ms-list").li.span(:text => "(Test) 3M").select
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please include more of the HTML code. Does the html change when the item in `"ms-selectable"` is clicked on? When you click on the first list are you saying the second list becomes the focus?

Answer (score 0):

This is a preliminary answer since you question needs more code to be able to determine what you really are trying to do:

```
@b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "(Test) 3M").hover
@b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "(Test) 3M").click
```

this assumes that your other list that you do not show in your question has the id like `/.*selected/`. So Watir should look for all of the `li` items that have an id that contains `selectable` and then look for the first one with the text `"(Test) 3M").select`.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution for this and added to the original question.

Comment: This worked @b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "(Test) 3M").hover so I can see the list item has the hover style applied. but using select or click did not work, no error shows in the terminal window.

Comment: Try what I edited above. The hover should make it visible, then the click can happen.

Comment: If it doesn't work, it may be because it is happening too fast, so you can change the second line to: `@b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "(Test) 3M").when_present.click` .

Comment: I had tried that and it did not work. This is what is working but only on the first selectable list.
@b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "*Quiche1").fire_event "onclick"
The original issue was pertaining to two selectable lists on the same page with similar html so I am not able to select from the second list.
For example:
@b.li(:id => /.*selectable/, :text => "* Afghanistan").fire_event "onclick"
will just cause the browser to freeze up. I am running ruby 2.0.0 on OSX with ruby watir webdriver in Firefox

Comment: At this point I'm just guessing. If you can post the code to somewhere that we can actually preview the behavior you are describing, that would be the only way I think I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the supplied HTML, there's no `select_list` element.  For example:

```
 b.ul(class: "ms-list").li(class: "ms-elem-selectable").span(text: "(Test) 3M").exists?
 #=> true
 b.ul(class: "ms-list").li(id: /selectable/).span(text: "(Test) 3M").exists?
 #=> true
 b.select_list(:class => "ms-list").li(class: "ms-elem-selectable").span(text: "(Test) 3M").exists?
 #=> false
```

If you want to click on "(Test) 3M", try something like:

```
 b.ul(class: "ms-list").li(class: "ms-elem-selectable").span(text: "(Test) 3M").click
```

Comment: I was unable to locate the element using your examples. I will try to clarify my question and add more html in hopes that there is a solution.